# asyncio and PyQt5: Inconsistent results when running a async function in QThreadPool

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, python-asyncio

I'm working on a PyQt5 project where I need to call an asyncio function (`self.handler.request_data`) without blocking the main UI.
I decided to run the async function inside a thread, and since I'll have multiple tasks concurrently, I opted for a QThreadPool.

Here's the code snippet that I've put together:

```
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    results = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, object)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, ident: str, func):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.ident = ident
        self.func = func

        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            res  = asyncio.run(self.func(self.ident))
            self.signals.results.emit(self.ident, res)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            self.signals.results.emit(self.ident, None)


class MainController(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        
    def request_data(self, ident: str):
        worker = Worker(ident, self.handler.request_data)
        worker.signals.results.connect(self.signal_testbed_response)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

The issue I'm facing is that this code works only occasionally for the very first requested ID.
The async function (self.handler.request_data) includes some logger messages, but they often don't show up (or just partially).
It seems like the event_loop inside the thread might not be completing the async function, leading to inconsistent outputs.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this issue? Thanks in advance!

(I know there are modules out there to combine the Qt event loop and asyncio, but I would have to change too much of my code to be able to use it)

Comment: you shouldn't do one `async.run` per request. You just gain the overhead of starting/stop an asyncio loop, with absolutely **none** of the possible benefits of running anything async, since there is no concurrent task in the same loop.

Comment: What exactly does `handler.request_data` do? It seems quite likely that asyncio isn't needed at all.

Comment: @ekhumoro request_data gathers responses from an API.

Comment: @Drimer I know *that*. But which *specific* API? What does it actually do? Does it invoke methods from third-party packages, and if so, which ones? It's impossible to answer your question properly without knowing the exact nature of the long-running task.

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry, I understand now. The function is gathering information using httpx. Based on the information, a local database is called which leads to another set of httpx requests.

Comment: @Drimer That isn't enough detail. According to the [httpx docs](https://www.python-httpx.org/), it has a "standard synchronous interface, but with async support if you need it". So it clearly ***can*** operate without the need for asyncio. But what about your actual code? If you call `handler.request_data` without `asyncio`, does it block or just return immediately? The fact that it returns a result suggests the former.

Comment: @Drimer PS: if you didn't write the code that provides `handler.request_data`, can you at least provide a link to the source code?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for your answer. I think I cannot completely follow. Even if I chance my function to a sync function, the functions I call inside this function will still be async. I am just moving the problem to a different function, but still not solving the issue, that the event loop is not finishing correctly? Regarding providing the code, it is unfortunately in-house code and I am unable to share it. There is not much going on other that a lot of requests are run asynchronously

Comment: If you can't use it in a multithread environment, the only option left for you that I can think of, is to use multiprocessing. But there's also the chance that the functions you're using may be badly implemented. You must make sure they really work at least outside the qt5 environment.